# Update swagger definition of an api in azure api management using github actions

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, swagger, github-actions, continuous-delivery

I'm building a CI/CD pipeline to automatically deploy my application to azure. This include a webapp, and 2 REST API, running in 3 different App Services. This is working ok so far.

The only thing remaining in my solution is that I have an API management with my 2 REST API added. Those APIs are built in C#.

What I need to do, is to automatically update the swagger definition in Azure API gateway once the APIs are deployed.

I'm currently using this action https://github.com/solidify/github-action-update-azapim

But for some reason this is throwing an error in my json (the swagger file). which is incorrect, because the swagger is actually working.

Does anyone have another github action suggestion to perform this task?